# CVSNT install hangs forever in Windows XP 64-bit

Tags: installation, cvs, cvsnt, wincvs

I need to access some source code stored on SourceForge using CVS.

I used (many computers ago) to use WinCVS, so I downloaded it from SourceForge and installed it on this machine, which runs Windows XP 64-bit (latest SP).

However, during the second part of the install, when it tries to install CVSNT, the install asks all the usual questions, and hangs during the actual install.

I have traced the install using ProcMon, and the installer starts up, creates a temporary file in my temp directory (which is on drive E:), and then executes it.

I can't see any particular reason why the install hangs - there is no obvious loop. Both the original installer, and the temporary file create 2 threads, and one thread exits. So I guess the other thread is waiting for something which never happens.

Any idea how to proceed from here?

Comment: I had similar problems getting TortoiseCVS to work in Windows 2008 R2.  It eventually installed, but the actual functionality was very sporadic.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the installer doesn't like the default installation path of `c:\Program files (x86)\cvsnt` — if you use `c:\cvsnt` the installer will proceed.

---

Update: this appears correct. If you still would like it in the default location under `C:\Program Files (x86)...`, use the 8.3 name (you can find it with `dir /x`), usually `C:\PROGRA~2`. As you can see in the screenshot, the last step appears correctly now. With a path with a space in it, it would hang forever.

[image]

Comment: Great, simple: this works. Never thought a space in the name would leave an application hanging these days.

Answer (score 2):

Second part of wincvs  --> cvsnt.exe   get hangs with  windows 7  due to incompatible, So you may try tortoiseCVS. It has the portable version and also working fine

Comment: Thanks, but I do not with to install TortoiseCVS, as it will pollute my Windows Explorer with another addon. I use TortoiseSVN extensively, but only use CVS for one project, which I only work on very occasionally, so would much prefer a separate, stand-alone app.

Comment: @Nikki, it might be that you don't have a choice, unless, fixing the incompatibility of CVSNT (it's open source after all). It hangs on me too, and I love the flexibility of TortoiseSVN/CVS. If you don't need it anymore, just uninstall it.

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION FOR Windows 8 64-bit:
On Windows 8 64-bit I was unable to install CVSNT (even to c:\cvsnt), but I solved the problem by simple copy the whole CVTNT directory from my old pc. 
I copied to C:\Program Files (x86)\cvsnt (exact location where wincvs expected to find cvsnt).

Comment: This is it, it has to be in this path exactly, the one that is in the installation by Default

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem on a machine at work (the difference being it was Windows 7 64-bit in our case). Even though the user had admin privileges, we were only able to resolve the issue by logging on directly as the admin before installing cvsnt.

Answer (score 0):

Do not install the version of CVSNT that comes with WinCVS. It's an old, outdated, buggy version. Install a later release (at least 2.5.0.4).